# How to write a conditional expect script to accept different set of passwords based on servers?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tcl, expect

My requirement is to write an **expect script** that will expect different set of passwords for different set of jump servers. Trouble is that I cannot generalize the
`expect 'Password:'`
as it is common between different servers. So my only way to identify the server is to read the banner before hand and check for a specific string and send the password accordingly.

I do not know how to read the **banner** in an expect command for `spawn ssh`

My code is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set host [lindex $argv 0]

set pass1 'xxx'
set pass2 'yy'

spawn ssh $host
expect "Password:*"
send "$pass1\r"
expect {
"Password:*" {
        send "$pass2\r"
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

Comment: you can expect "host name .*"  -- given your hostname of every sever will be different.

Comment: i expect is for password fields right.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that you would need to identify the server based on some string in a banner it returns when you already have its identity in the $host variable. Unless the specified hostname resolves to multiple servers that do not share a common password.

Assuming that situation and a banner returned by each host saying "Welcome to *servername*", you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set host [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh $host

expect {
    -ex {Welcome to server1} {
        set pass "xxx"
    }
    -ex {Welcome to server2} {
        set pass "yy"
    }
    default {
        # Something unexpected happened
        exit 1
    }
}

expect {
    -ex "Password: " {
        send "$pass\r"
    }
}
```

This first looks for the welcome message and sets the pass variable to the password for the specific server. Then it sends the selected password to the server after it finds the Password prompt.